# get ordered nodes in components of directed acyclic networkx DiGraph

Tags: python, networkx, directed-graph

I have a directed graph with subgraphs where the order of nodes is important.

Example my graph would have two subgraphs, all linear
`1-->2-->3 & 9-->8-->7-->6`

**note:** the node names will be random and unique, no cycles in the graphs

```
NG = nx.DiGraph()
NG.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3)])
NG.add_edges_from([(9,8),(8,7),(7,6)])
```

I need to get the subgraphs or a list of nodes in the subgraphs with the nodes ordered according to their connection.

I've tried

```
[i.nodes() for i in list(nx.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs(NG))]
```

resulting in  list of nodelists, almost right, but not ordered according to their connections:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [8, 9, 6, 7]]
```

How would I need to proceed to get the list of ordered nodelists. i.e:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [9, 8, 7, 6]]
```

Comment: I edited your title to more closely match the question.  Please check that it's okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are sure these are "Directed Acyclic Graphs".

Then `nx.topological_sort(G)` sorts the nodes in a graph according to the order you want: that is, if `u` appears before `v`, that means there is no path from `v` to `u` (but possibly a path from `u` to `v`).  If you use `nx.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs(G)` you get a generator for the subgraphs you're interested in.  So the approach I recommend is to first find the subgraphs and then sort the nodes.

```
[nx.topological_sort(H) for H in nx.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs(NG)]
```

Should get what you want.

---

An alternate more efficient method:

The previous code will not be the most efficient code possible, but it is simple.  Creating each subgraph `H` takes time that could be avoided.  A more efficient method would do `weakly_connected_components(NG)` (which generates lists of the nodes in each subgraph rather than the subgraph themselves).  This would create lists like you have already.  Then you do the topological sort:

```
[nx.topological_sort(NG, nbunch=subgraph_nodes) for subgraph_nodes in nx.weakly_connected_components(NG)]
```

This will be more efficient.  What it does is first it generates the list of nodes in each component.  Then it goes through sorting the nodes in each component.  If you do this, you should take a look at the [source for topological_sort](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/algorithms/dag.html#topological_sort).  It will return a sorted list of all nodes that are reachable from any node it `nbunch`.  In your case this is just `nbunch`, but more generally it does not just have to return `nbunch`.

---

Note: in your code there is no need for `list(...)`.  You would get the same result without it.

Comment: Thanks, indeed this is what I intend to do. I'm 100% sure each subgraph is a DAG, the nodes represent physically separated objects in linear space. Cycles or branches are not possible